# Use Entity Framework in .net 4.0 with Oracle database - possible?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I am building an application that targets .Net 4.0 (cannot be higher for the moment). I need to get access to Oracle Db (11g) and I wanted to use Entity Framework.

To be able to do that I know that I have to use:

- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

The first one is no problem, however when I try to install the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` NuGet package, I get the following message:

> Could not install package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
>   12.1.2400'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

When I change target framework to 4.5.2 the package installs and everything works fine so I am assuming that this package is somehow dependent on .Net framework ~4.5.

Is there any workaround to make it work with .Net 4.0?

**Edit:**

Just to be clear, I have instaled `Entity Framework 6.1.3` as this is prerequisite for installing Oracle's EF provider

Answer (score 1):

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` has a dependency to `EntityFramework` (>= 6.0.0 && < 7.0.0) so you can install first `Entity Framework 6.1.3` from nuget that version works on .Net Framework 4.0 and then `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework`

Comment: Much better. Do note that you can just edit your existing answer instead of deleting and creating a new one (granted, in some cases votes won't change but if you reply to any comments you might get lucky).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I started answering today :)

Comment: @DamianGalletini `Entity Framework` is a prerequisite for `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` and I know it works with .Net 4.0 but the latter does not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found that `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.2.1100` it was built for .net 4.5.

[Assembly explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKVrC.png)

So, I believe that we can not use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.2.1100` with .net 4.0.

upd:
I received the explanation of that situation from Oracle .NET Team:

> **From**: "Oracle .NET Team"
>
> **Date**: 16 августа 2017 г., 0:58:31
>
> **Theme**: **Reply: [NuGet Gallery] Message for owners of the package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework'**
>
> Hi Yuriy,
>
> Microsoft desupported [.NET Framework 4 support for versions 4.5.1 and
>   earlier](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework) as of January, 2016. In the newest ODP.NET release, Oracle
>   follows that support policy.
>
> Oracle did not change ODP.NET such that
>   it only works in .NET 4.5.2 and newer versions. Microsoft did not
>   change .NET that prevents backwards compatibility. It's actually
>   likely that the new ODP.NET will work fine with the older .NET 4
>   versions. I'm not aware of any incompatibilities. **Oracle just doesn't
>   officially support nor certify the earlier .NET versions anymore**.
>
> Regards, Oracle .NET Team

Comment: Do you have any sources you can quote or other information to back up your answer here?

Comment: Well, it's just my opinion but I added a screenshot to prove it.