# Entity Framework exception for Oracle. Underlying provider failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I simply can add and edit a table, views in Entity Framework model for Oracle. But when I tried to retrieve data from a table, then an error occurs

> Underlying provider failed to open

I am using Visual Studio 2015, Oracle Managed Data Access 12.2.1100 and Entity Framework 6.

Please help me about this issue.

Comment: Did you check the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838682/use-entity-framework-in-net-4-0-with-oracle-database-possible)?

Comment: **SHOW US SOME CODE!** What are you doing in code? What are you trying to accomplish? Remember: we can neither see your screen, nor read your mind - you have the **show us here** what you're doing - then *maybe* we can help ......

Comment: My problem is solved. But the problem is very funny. 

I have install both visual studio 2015, Oracle Developer Tool for VS2015  and visual studio 2017, Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017. 

I have my TNSNames.ora into Oracle Developer tools for VS2015.
Currently i am working in visual studio 2015. When i am trying to refresh my entity framework model then model accessing tnsnames.ora from Oralce Dev Tools for VS2015 but when i tried to executing any code it tried to read tnsnames.ora from Oralce Dev Tools for VS2017. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. But the problem is very funny. I have install both visual studio 2015, Oracle Developer Tool for VS2015 and visual studio 2017, Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017. I have my TNSNames.ora into Oracle Developer tools for VS2015. Currently i am working in visual studio 2015. When i am trying to refresh my entity framework model then model accessing tnsnames.ora from Oralce Dev Tools for VS2015 but when i tried to executing any code it tried to read tnsnames.ora from Oralce Dev Tools for VS2017.