# Use Entity Framework in .net 4.0 with Oracle database

Tags: oracle, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6

I#m having the same problem as in issue: [Use Entity Framework in .net 4.0 with Oracle database - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838682/use-entity-framework-in-net-4-0-with-oracle-database-possible)

The question was not answered in my opinion. So I would like to know if there is a possibility of using EF6 with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework for a .NET4.0 project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Entity Framework in .net 4.0 with Oracle database - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838682/use-entity-framework-in-net-4-0-with-oracle-database-possible)

Comment: sorry it is a duplicate. get more reputation by answering questions to be able to [add a bounty to the original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and request additional information.